# Python 3 File I/O won't sum

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to write this code for the following week and have been getting int or float subscript errors or the code will print but not sum the totals. I created a .txt file with customer name, service (meal, lodging, cost - in that order) separated by semicolons; and need to print to the interpreter the total for each category.

> A hotel salesperson enters sales in a .txt file. Each line contains
>   the following seperated by semicolons: Name of client, service sold,
>   amount of sale, and the date of of the event. Write a program that
>   reads the file and displays the total amount for each service
>   category.
>   Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is incorrect.

```
infile = open("123.txt", "r")
try:
    for line in infile:
        item = line.split(":")
        service = item[1]
        cost = float(item[2])
        sum1 = (0.0)

    if service == "Dinner":
            costDin = cost + sum1
            print (costDin, "Dinner")
    elif service == "Concert":
            costCon = cost + sum1
            print (costCon, "Concert")
    elif service == "Lodging":
            costLod = cost + sum1
            print (costLod, "Lodging")

except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")

except ValueError as exception:
    print("Error: str(exception)")

infile.close()
```

Comment: `:` is not a semicolon.

Comment: noisypixy - you are right, sorry for the typo, the items are separated by a single colon. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: you may want to add whats your current status/output and what you expect

Comment: Currently when the file is run it prints out the cost and service on separate lines. The txt file has multiple lines in the format listed above (customer:service:cost:date). I would like to create code that prints, "Total amount for dinner is 'x'" (on first line), "Total amount of lodging its 'x'" (on line 2), etc.  I have tried to run a for loop under the if loop and keep getting int/float not subscript able errors